# "load", "beforeunload" event listeners not working in Salesforce Data Cloud Web SDK

Tags: javascript, salesforce, addeventlistener, event-listener, user-interaction

I'm trying to add an event listener inside *listeners* in *PageConfig* in Data Cloud Web SDK Sitemap to track the interactions on the website.

*listeners* - An array of event listeners created using the SalesforceInteractions.listener function. These events listen for customer interactions that trigger events to send through the Web SDK.

So when I add
`window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (e) => { console.log("Page unload"); })`
The code is executed correctly and `Page unload` is printed in console.

But When I use
`SalesforceInteractions.listener("beforeunload", (e) => { console.log("Page unload"); })`  
This peice of Code is not executed and `Page Unload` is not printed in console.

Is there any way where I can use `load` or `unload` event listeners using `SalesforceInteractions.listener()`?
Or am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Maybe yoiu schould ask here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com